# How to avoid the tablesorter pager adding a hash value at the end of the url while navigating from one page to another-Jquery simplePagination plugin

Tags: jquery, pagination, tablesorter

Im using a tablesorter pager for page navigation (simplePagination plugin). The pagination works fine only with an issue that it sets the hash value to page1 while navigating between pages. 
for ex: i go from page 1 to page2 (assuming there are 10 pages with 100 records, 10 per page), it sets the hash to #page2 viz: http://www.index.html/#page1 and  #page3 when on 3rd page and so on..

js:

```
$("#pagination").pagination({
    items: items.length,
    itemsOnPage: 10,
    labelText: 'Showing',
    cssStyle: 'light-theme',
    onInit: function () {
        startItem = ((this.currentPage * this.itemsOnPage) + 1);
        endItem = ((startItem - 1) + this.itemsOnPage);
        if (endItem > this.items) {
            endItem = this.items;
        }
        $('#pagination').prepend(
            '<div class="pagination-addon">' +
            '<label class="pagination-label">' + this.labelText + '</label> ' +
            '<label class="pagination-start-item">' + startItem + '</label> - ' +
            '<label class="pagination-end-item">' + endItem + '</label> of ' +
            '<label class="pagination-total-items">' + this.items + '</label>' +
            '</div>');
    },
    onPageClick: function (pageNumber) {
        this.onInit();
    }
});
```

Is there any way to turn off the page hash (#page1, #page2) when i navigate between the pages using the simplePagination plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/flaviusmatis/simplePagination.js/issues/31), you can add a `return false` to the `onPageClick` callback method:

So change the callback in your code to this:

```
onPageClick: function (pageNumber) {
    this.onInit();
    return false;
}
```